# Render de componente Primefaces con ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

lo mio es mas que nada una duda que no me deja tranquilo. Sucede que tengo un codigo que me funciona perfectamente(un proyecto JSF con primefaces), pero en una parte me muestra un warning que dice ***"Error de sintaxis en EL"*** sobre un componente.
Pongo solo parte del codigo en cuestion:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{dropdownView.country}" style="width:150px">
<p:ajax listener="#{dropdownView.onCountryChange}" update="city, opcionActual"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:outputLabel id="opcionActual" value="#{dropdownView.country}" rendered="#{dropdownView.pintar = true}" ></p:outputLabel>
```

En resumen, desde el *p:selectOneMenu* llamo con ajax al *p:outputLabel* y en el atributo rendered de este ultimo decido si lo pinto o no. 
Primero puse:

```
#{dropdownView.pintar == true}
```

pero no me funcionó, por lo que simplemente le quité un signo "=" para probar y funcionó:

```
#{dropdownView.pintar = true}
```

Pese a ello en el eclipse me muestra el warning que mencioné al principio, tendrá alguna consecuencia futura que aun no logro ver??

Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El atributo "render" espera un valor booleano (true o false), cuando usas un único signo de igual estás realizando una asignación, lo que debes hacer es una comparación booleana, por lo tanto hay que utilizar doble igual "`==`". El atributo debería quedar:

```
rendered="#{dropdownView.pintar == true}"
```

O si dropdownView.pintar ya es un objeto booleano entonces puedes dejarlo sin el igual:

```
rendered="#{dropdownView.pintar}"
```